# Grafana + Prometheus how to use regex in query metrics?

Tags: prometheus, grafana, metrics

We are dynamically adding new metrics. Is it possible to use regex in Grafana query metrics?

```
application_test_total{color="0"}
```

```
application_test_total{color="1"}
```

```
application_test_total{color="2"}
```

How to avoid this?

```
sum(application_test_total{color="0"})+sum(application_test_total{color="1"})
```

Is it possible to replace with this?

```
application_test_total{color="[0-9]{2}"}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace:

```
sum(application_test_total{color="0"})+sum(application_test_total{color="1"})
```

To:

```
sum(application_test_total{color=~"[0-9]{1}"})
```

Comment: This not work. Grafana version v6.6.2 (3fa63cfc34).

Comment: There was a "~" missing. I fixed the answer.